# linq to class of T

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have below:

```
var attributes = from root in doc.Elements()
                 where root.Name == "quran"
                 from suras in root.Elements()
                 where suras.Name == "suras"
                 from sura in suras.Elements()
                 where sura.Name == "sura"
                 from atts in sura.Attributes()
                 select atts;

List<Sura> item = new List<Sura>();
```

and Class

```
public class Sura
{
    private string _aya;
    private string _ayaTranslation;
    System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment _ayaAlignment;
    public string Aya
    {
        get { return _aya; }
        set { _aya = value; }
    }
    public string AyaTranslation
    {
        get { return _ayaTranslation; }
        set { _ayaTranslation = value; }
    }
}
```

below is the XML

```
<quran>
  <suras>
    <sura Aya="123" AyaTranslation="321"></sura>
    <sura Aya="123" AyaTranslation="321"></sura>
    <sura Aya="123" AyaTranslation="321"></sura>
  </suras>
</quran>
```

I want to convert "att" to list "item", But I have no idea how do it. Though I googled, but doesn't help.

Comment: What do you mean by `att`?

Comment: very sorry, it's "attributes"

Comment: possible, will be better use [xmlserializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need `attributes` list, you can get `List<Sura>` directly from your document.

```
var items = (from sura in doc.Root.Element("suras").Elements("sura")
             select new Sura {
                  Aya = (string)sura.Attribute("Aya"),
                  AyaTranslation = (string)sura.Attribute("AyaTranslation")
             }).ToList();
```

As you can see, I removed couple `from`/`where` from your query. If you only expect one element with given name it's easier to use `Element("name")`. And you can always get document root element from `Root` property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can I just convert (byte)sura.Attribute("Aya") ? It's not working

Comment: Because your property is typed as string.

Comment: I changed it to Byte but this statement (byte)sura.Attribute("Aya") is not working...

Comment: There is no `XAttribute` to `byte` conversion defined. Try using `(int)` first:  `Aya = (byte)(int)sura.Attribute("Aya")`